# Python igraph calculate modularity for each cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph, modularity

I have an network that I would like to analyze using the multilevel community detection algorithm in iGraph. I heard that multilevel in igraph is the same with Louvain method. I know that Louvain method only output the optimal modularity, but i need to know how to output other cluster modularity.

I have tried to use `return_levels = True` but the result is

`igraph.clustering.VertexClustering object at 0x117364518`

and if i not using `return_levels = True` the output only showing the optimal modularity

Here is my code for community_multilevel:

```
from igraph import *

graph= Graph.Read_Ncol('Dummy.txt',names=True,directed=False,weights=True)

implementLouvain = graph.community_multilevel()

print (implementLouvain)
outputModularity = graph.modularity(implementLouvain)
print("Modularity Optimal Value",outputModularity)
```

inside Dummy.txt

```
a b 1
a c 1
a d 1
b d 1
c d 1
b g 1
e f 1
e g 1
e h 1
f h 1
g h 1
a g 1
```

the output is look like this

```
Clustering with 8 elements and 2 clusters
[0] a, b, c, d
[1] g, e, f, h

Modularity Optimal Value:  0.33333333333333337
```

My goal is to output modularity for each cluster its like this

[0] a,b,c,d

Modularity [0]: 0.xxxxxxx

is there any solution for my problem ? or am i missing something ?
Thank You~

Comment: You are missing something. Modularity is a property of the graph, not of any cluster.

Comment: Oh i get it, so it is impossible to get modularity for each cluster right ? @Paul

Comment: That is correct.