# Find modularity of each cluster using networkx

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have i graph and im trying to find the modularity of each cluster. So to find this i implement the following steps:

1. I found the biggest connected component of the graph(giantCC)
2. I found all communities of the graph using greedy_modularity communities function
3. And now im trying to find the cluster modularity using the modularity function from networkx and im getting an error

Here is my code:

```
cc = sorted(nx.connected_components(g), key=len, reverse=True)
giantCC = g.subgraph(cc[0])
print("Giant cc size: " + str(giantCC.number_of_nodes()))

communities = list(greedy_modularity_communities(giantCC))
communities = sorted(communities, key=len, reverse=True)
print('Number of clusters: ' + str(len(communities)))
communities = [list(x) for x in communities]

cluster_modularity = nx_comm.modularity(giantCC, communities[0])
print('Modularity: ' + str(cluster_modularity))
```

When i call the function modularity im getting the following error:
[image]

Why im getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the modularity calculation function you are using ([this one](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.quality.modularity.html#networkx.algorithms.community.quality.modularity)) uses all communitites to calculate modularity, since it is a value of the partitioning of your network.
So you should use it like this:

```
cluster_modularity = nx_comm.modularity(giantCC, communities)
print('Modularity: ' + str(cluster_modularity))
```

Also, I would recommend using the Louvain heuristics for partitioning of graphs, a networkX's API using this method is already available [here](https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Comment: Can you find modularity of each clusters using igraph?

Comment: @stackword_0, looking for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395946/python-igraph-calculate-modularity-for-each-cluster